# How to get facebook access token that works without logging in everytime?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, graph

I got page access token from ***facebook.com/tools/explorer with perrmissions (publish_pages) .
tried to extend its time

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=appid&client_secret=appsecret&fb_exchange_token=accesstoken`

Now it expires after 90days

it worked fine at that moment.I logged out of my account and  After  2hr i tried to post again with the same page access token
it saying
**`Error validating access token: Session has expired on Monday, 02-Dec-19 20:00:00 PST. The current time is Monday, 02-Dec-19 23:37:03 PST`**

Comment: I am trying to post in facebook pages (by using api without logging) everytime the user/admin clicks on a button to post on facebook page.

Comment: That does not sound as if you _really_ have an extended page token there. Those can get invalidated before their expiry f.e. if the user that granted them changes their password - but a mere logout alone should not cause this.

Comment: i can see its expiry time here ```https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/```  @04FS

Comment: Can you show before / after screenshots of that? (You can blur the token, leave maybe the first and last couple characters visible, so it is clear it is the same token.)